# Sampling with Chi2 distribution with degrees of freedom

Tags: r, distribution, statistics-bootstrap

I am working on statistic field and I am a junior in field as I am a toxicologist.

I would like to ask you how to do this in R.
I want to sample a GSD (Geometric Standard Deviation) value from a modified Chi2 distribution with degrees of freedom (5 here) and this value is calculated with the data GM = 1, GSD = 1.98. I don't know what it does really mean and I don't how to get a distribution with Chi2 in R to have a random value.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some data and your previous trails and errors? Best regards

Comment: `modified Chi2 distribution` how it is modified, do you know?

Answer (score 0):

In R, you can generate values based on predefined functions using `r*` command. For Chi^2 function, there's `rchisq`.

```
hist(rchisq(1000, df = 5))
```